# how to use execute in nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I wish to populate a field in my application using execute when running nightwatchjs tests

I have tried the following:

```
.execute("document.getElementByClassName('.price').setAttribute('value', '19.99')")
```

This does not work, field is not populated however I do not get an error. Can someone explain what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

p.s - I know I can populate the field by using .setValue('.price', '9
.99') but I wish to learn how to do it via execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. There is only small changes.

```
.execute("document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].setAttribute('value', '19.99')")
```

Comment: Hi Murthi, thanks for your suggestion, however this did not work for me.

Comment: Remove dot in the class name and try again.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try now and let me know

Comment: You can try the following code. .execute("document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].value= '19.99')")

Comment: Hi, took me a while to get back to this, but yes your last suggestion did the trick. Thank you for your help.